# Modifying password validation rules for ASP.NET Identity 2 during runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-identity

Is it possible to change the password validation rules (using the passwordValidator class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.passwordvalidator(v=vs.108).aspx) during runtime?
I cant think why it wouldn't be possible, but I just don't know then how the system would handle changes to validation rules for existing users.
Has anyone done this? Or know if it can be done?

Comment: You can implement your own `PasswordValidator` class that can do whatever you need at runtime.

Comment: @trailmax interesting idea! something i had considered, but i just wondered if the default system can handle dynamic changes during runtime that was all. Its a difficult question for SO as its quite a specific question!

Comment: It is not overly difficult question: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PasswordValidator